# Keeps getting rejected by Apple for a geo-restricted app. What should I do?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

Apple started to reject our app because they can't access our app because of geo-restriction. We have also a video which shows our app's demonstration in the review process. And Apple Review Team can't access app in U.S.A. It's a gambling app and it must be geo-restricted according to the App Store Review Guidelines.

> **5.3.4 Apps that offer real money gaming (e.g. sports betting, poker, casino games, horse racing) or lotteries must have necessary licensing and permissions in the locations where the App is used, must be geo-restricted to those locations, and must be free on the App Store. Illegal gambling aids, including card counters, are not permitted on the App Store. Lottery apps must have consideration, chance, and a prize.**

We show a pop up to user which says basically that they could not access to the app because of the geo-restricted.

Apple Review Team's Response:

> **5.3.4 Guideline 2.1 - Performance - App Completeness**
>
> **We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on iPhone running iOS 13.5 on Wi-Fi.**
>
> **Specifically, upon launch, your app displayed an error message. All apps submitted to the App Store must function correctly and provide access to all features and content at the time of review, regardless of network, device capability, location, etc.**
>
> **Next Steps**
>
> **To resolve this issue, please run your app on a device to identify any issues, then revise and resubmit your app for review.**
>
> **If we misunderstood the intended behavior of your app, please reply to this message in Resolution Center to provide information on how these features were intended to work.**
>
> **For new apps, uninstall all previous versions of your app from a device, then install and follow the steps to reproduce the issue. For updates, install the new version as an update to the previous version, then follow the steps to reproduce the issue.**

How can we make the app geo-restrict and also provide access to all features?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Specifically, upon launch, your app displayed an error message.

Was your error message clear to the user, explaining what had happened and what they must do to resolve the issue? Did you explain this restriction in your App Store description (particularly if you're submitting to any store where the restriction would apply), and in your App Store submission? Even if the user cannot proceed, they should have a good experience. It shouldn't just be an alert saying "go away." A legitimate user might launch your product while traveling, and it should be clear that they need to wait until they get home.

> If we misunderstood the intended behavior of your app, please reply to this message in Resolution Center to provide information on how these features were intended to work.

This is the key point. Contact them. You may need to give them a backdoor that unlocks it for the Apple site. You may need to give them a special login. They may work with you in other ways. But contact them.

When you say "keeps getting rejected," that suggest more to the story. Did you contact them and did they tell you other things? Did you just keep submitting?

Comment: Pop up says why they can't use while they are abroad. And we tried to communicate with Apple. We asked what should we do etc. They did not say anything. They just kept saying the same things over and over. We will try to not force user to go home screen. They will use the app but they can't bet. Maybe it can work.

Comment: The ideal case (in my experience submitting things to Apple) is that your app would completely work (let them look around, see what the app does), but just not allow bets, like you suggest here. Probably with a banner at the top or bottom to let the user know that they're in that mode and won't be allowed to actually place anything. That way it's always a good experience, and if someone is out of the region they can perhaps set things up, and then place the bet when they're back home. Best of luck!

Comment: (BTW, I very much appreciate the frustration trying to get clear answers from Apple. I've been there. It's still the path you have to take, but I appreciate they often will not answer you in a useful way.)

Comment: Thank you @RobNapier

Answer (score 0):

even though your app is geo restricted,you need to implement code for testing purpose so that they can test all the functionality of the app.i suggest you create a user for testing that will bypass the geo restriction and specify the name and password at notes in app submission.